# Logically find the cost of a fruit

Tags: pattern, lateral-thinking

If Banana costs 45 cents and
If Apple costs 30 cents and 
If Pineapple costs 60 cents

How much would a Mango cost.
Give an explantion

Comment: It appears that [SteveV's answer below](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/80593/4421) is likely the intended answer, but as [JonMark Perry has demonstrated below](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/80596/4421), several different answers are possible.  On Puzzling.SE, we require puzzles to have one verifiably correct answer.  If several different potential answers all fit the problem as stated, then it is considered "too broad" and is not a good fit for this site.

Comment: why the negative votes, is it because I put it in wrong tag?

Comment: I think @GentlePurpleRain's explanation is why you'd be seeing downvotes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would cost

> 30 cents

Because the cost appears to be

> 15 cents per vowel in their name.  Since Mango has 2 vowels, 30 cents total.

Comment: Aw, man. You beat me to it by 12 seconds.

Comment: This is a correct answer

Answer (score 3):

> 45 cent. Each run of a consonant counts 15 cent.

Comment: This rule leads to an incorrect Apple price.

Comment: @SteveV; no it doesn't - the pp counts as one run of a consonant, hence only gets 15cents.